# In TypeScript, how to find the type of an object after JSON stringify+parse?

Tags: typescript

If an object has unserializable properties (e.g. methods), converting that object to JSON and back will result in a new object of altered type. How would we implement a generic type like `JSONTypeOf<T>` that tells us the type of this new object, given the original?

```
const squirrel = {
  name: "Töski",
  nuts: 392,

  consumeNut() {
    this.nuts -= 1;
  }
}

// How do we get the type of this new object?
const afterJSONSquirrel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(squirrel))
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYKZvN) meet your needs? I can imagine a lot of edge cases where your expectations and mine might differ, so please check it thoroughly before responding, there's no need to rush.  If it works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If you're pursuing a generic utility, don't ignore the presence of built-in and custom [`toJSON()` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) — you'll need to consider their return types as well.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more corner cases, but it's roughly

```
function JSONClone<T>(v: T): Clone<T> { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)) }

const squirrel = {
  name: "Töski",
  nuts: 392,
  consumeNut() {
    this.nuts -= 1;
  }
}
const copy = JSONClone(squirrel)
//    ^?
// const copy: {
//     name: string;
//     nuts: number;
// }

type Clone<T> =
  | T extends number | string | null ? T
  : T extends Function ? never
  : T extends any[] ? { [K in keyof T]: Clone<T[K]> }
  : T extends Date ? string
  : T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T
    as[Clone<T[K]>] extends [never] ? never : K
    ]: Clone<T[K]>
  }
  : never
```

Comment: `Clone<T>` instead of `Clone<T[K]>` inside the array case is 